# Set Auto increment to a column in Sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have used the following code to create a database using Sqlite. I have set auto increment to a column. When I try to insert values to the table it gives error.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME
                + " (user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username VARCHAR,age VARCHAR, zipcode VARCHAR,gender VARCHAR,isstored VARCHAR);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ("
                + "\"" + name + "\"," + "\"" + age
                + "\",\"" + zip + "\",\"" + gender + "\", \""
                + "ok" + "\");");
```

Error:

```
 09-28 09:44:54.545: E/AndroidRuntime(3825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity ComponentInfo{com.readometer/com.readometer.ReadometerSplash}: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table USERDETAILS has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO USERDETAILS Values ("kumar","23","1234","M", "ok");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to insert you should insert it this way. The SQlite framework will insert the auto-incremented values to the user_id column by itself.

```
INSERT INTO test.authors (username,age, zipcode,gender,isstored) VALUES ("kumar","23","1234","M", "ok");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something cleaner, first declare all your column attributes as constants, and then use the following for example to do a proper insert in the DB:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(USERNAME, name);
values.put(AGE, age
values.put(ZIPCODE, zip);
values.put(GENDER, gender);
values.put(STORED, ok);
db.insert(SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SQLiteDatabase s =getWritableDatabase();
s.execSQL( "INSERT INTO requestmsg (username ,age , zipcode ,gender ,isstored ) " +                 "VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + age+ "','" +  zip+ "','"+gender+"','ok')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

> ```
> sql = "INSERT INTO "+ SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + "( username,age,zipcode,gender,isstored) " +
> "VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + age + "','" + zip+ "' ,'" +gender + "' ,'"ok"' )";
> db.execSQL(sql);
> ```